# Django UserCreationForm Meta fields

Tags: django

I created customized usercreationform

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users #personal User model
        fields = (
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "adresse",
            "phonenumber",
        )
```

The simple question is if it works without "password1", "password2" in fields?

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users #personal User model
        fields = (
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "adresse",
            "phonenumber",
            "password1",
            "password2",
        )
```

if both this code and code above work, what makes difference between the two codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you define in Meta :

```
Model = Users #your own model
```

So, the two options will work if you have these fields in your own model. Because in Meta, fields will point your model, not Django User model.

Nevertheless, in your model you must not have 2 fields "password". Only one. In UserCreationForm

```
Class Meta:
    Model = User
```

And the UserCreationForm adds two fields "password1" and "password2" for a special clean method. If password1==password2 then it will save a hash of the password in User.password.

You should never save a plain text password in your database for security reasons.

UserCreationForm is a easy way to create user (with a unique username). If you want to add some attributes Django recommands to make your own model (named Person for example) with a foreign Key to django.contrib.auth.User and all the other fields you want to add to the user in your own model.

I Hope I answered to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By the way, I use my personal Users model as abstractuser. and i didn't defined password fields in my Users model

Answer (score 0):

from my current Django knowledge the UserCreationForm is a convenience form provided by Django for creating new users. It includes validation for password complexity and password confirmation.

The UserCreationForm includes two fields: password1 and password2.

- password1: This is where the user can enter their desired password.
- password2: This is a confirmation field where the user re-enters the same password to confirm it.
  The form will validate that password1 and password2 match. If they don't, the form will raise a validation error.

If you want to use UserCreationForm without password1 and password2, you would need to create a custom user creation form. However, getting rid of these fields would typically go against best practices imo.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views